# What cost function to use for Multi-label classification (possible tags are somewhere between 100 - 500)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, loss-function

I have been trying to solve a Multi-label classification problem and my end goal is to predict tags for each image. On an average, every image has tags between the range of (5 - 10) associated with them.

So I used tf.nn.sigmoid_with_cross_entropy as my loss function but the problem is now the number of classes are in 100's and at any given point of time one image will be associated with only 5-10 tags so let's say for the sake of argument we have 100 possible tags I want the model to train on and for this particular image let's the label vector looks like this :

[1,1,1,1,0,0,0...] (... mean it has only 0's) Which mean it has only 4 relevant tags.

And let's say my predictions are pretty bad and it predicted all the 4 tags wrong so now it's output vector looks like this:

[0,0,0,0,0,0,0...] Which mean it could not predict anything

But even though the model did pretty bad in predicting, mathematically :

**Accuracy**: 96/100

**Sigmoid cross entropy loss**: 0.73 (approx.)

But if the situation were different and instead of 100 labels we had only 4 the accuracy number and loss value would have been different

**Accuracy**: 0/4

**Sigmoid cross entropy loss**: 1.3 (approx.)

In the 1st situation mathematically the model performed well but actually the performance was pretty bad.

So my question here is how can I fix this? Are there any custom loss function which I can use to get rid of this problem? As because of this my model is actually not learning anything at all and converging very quickly.

Comment: As i understood your question you are working on unbalanced Data set.If you are working on unbalanced data set don't estimate your performance by accuracy. you could try sampling or SMOTE.

Comment: I have an unbalanced dataset but that is not the problem here, the only reason I mentioned accuracy is just to explain what is happening. The actual problem here is because I have so many tags and only 5-10 tags can coexist at any given time the loss automatically becomes low irrespective of my prediction about those 5-10 tags are right or wrong. So more than an evaluation technique i need a loss function that takes this into account.

Comment: @NeerajKomuravalli Have you got the answer ? please share.